# expo react-navigation 5.x, Bottom Tab Navigator works differently on IOS and Android when wrapped in Drawer Navigator

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

wanted to implement Bottom Tab Navigator with a Custom Styled Central Tab Icon and a DrawerNavigator. When the BottomTab is wrapped with DrawerNavigator, the Center Button that has roundness gets clipped on Android (ok on IOS)

For Android

[image]

For IOS it is fine, with or without Drawer wrap
[image]

A working snack of above is below to toggle both states (with DrawerNavigator + Bottom Navigator Vs Bottom Navigator)

Again issue is only on Android

https://snack.expo.dev/@haniq313/bottomtab-custom-center-icon

The issue is not there with react-navigation 6.x. But need to make this work on React-Navigation 5.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9615

for this looking for a solution. It is a known bug in navigation 5.x and as metioned can be fixed by Wrapping the whole Tab.Navigator in a

<Pressable style={{ flex: 1, }} disabled > <Tab.Navigatior> ......... </Tab.Navigator>